# Save image created from function imagecopy

Tags: php, image, resize

When I create image from this:

```
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
```

I can output it like this:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

But how can I save it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code to save the image.

```
imagepng($imagename, $mapimage_path  , 0);
```